# Wordpress category reappears after deleting

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to delete a category in Wordpress, but it fails. To be precise it says it's deleted, but when I refresh the page, it's still there. Moreover when I tried to delete it directly in DB the same happens - I delete it, and then it comes back under a new ID.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing the Theme and check deletion operation.
2. Try disabling plugins one by one and try deleting category.
3. See if any errors coming on firebug console.

There might be some code which is causing the issue on WordPress admin end.